# Fit size android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: here is my photo]

Hey ! I am an amateur, can you tell me how to make my background layout become fit to my screen ?

As you can see it still have a little gap to my emulator. I already make it to `match_parent` but it didn't work and I'm still confused

Thanks

Comment: Make sure there is no padding or margin on your parent layout nor child layout. And it will be better if you provide full code of your xml file.

Comment: please share your xml file.

Comment: Add scaletype fitXY (i think fitxy is better than centercrop for you) in imageview

Answer (score 2):

its because your image not at the same width and height as the  screen  so even if u use match parent it will make a gap .
try to use  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`